# Using Contact Form 7 wpcf7_feedback_response to output html in the response?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to output a hidden iFrame that will load in the AJAX response after submitting the form. It just outputs it as a string currently. Is this possible to do any other way?

```
add_filter('wpcf7_feedback_response', function($response, $result) {
    $iframe_url = "https://software.loks.com/handler239" . "email=" . urlencode($_POST['email']) . "&company=" . urlencode($_POST['company']) . "&phone=" . urlencode($_POST['phone']);

    $iframe_html = '<iframe src="' . $iframe_url . '" width="1" height="1" style="display:none;"></iframe>';
    $response['message'] = $iframe_html;

    return $response;
}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: How is the string looking alike?

Comment: @LajosArpad Like this https://prnt.sc/juAyHniazJtT

Comment: what do you receive if you check it on the network tab?

Comment: The part eventually responsible appears to be in the client-side script, https://github.com/rocklobster-in/contact-form-7/blob/master/includes/js/src/submit.js#L86 - the `.wpcf7-response-output` elements get looped over there, and `div.innerText = response.message;` is assigned. Assigning to `innerText` will not get any HTML code parsed, but treated as text only. [...]

Comment: [...] So you would either need to modify that script part directly (not recommendable, will be problematic regarding plugin updates); or find some way to fix this "after the fact" - either see if CF7 fires another event after this that you could subscribe to, or by implementing a MutationObserver. A simple `div.innerHTML = div.innerText` should do the trick then, to re-read the text content of the div and have it set & parsed as HTML instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ongoing issue with CF7 plugin and its author simply ignores requests to enable richer response messages citing security concerns, which albeit has some merit, should really be left to the website admin to decide how to configure/customise their site.

You can see multiple requests/issues raised on the GitHub plugin repo, [here](https://github.com/rocklobster-in/contact-form-7/issues/396), [here](https://github.com/rocklobster-in/contact-form-7/issues/345) and [here](https://github.com/rocklobster-in/contact-form-7/issues/419), which have all been closed and tagged as invalid, and if you raise a concern more than once you get blocked from the author :(.  The author closed this door with this [update](https://github.com/rocklobster-in/contact-form-7/pull/397).

In the above linked issues, you will find multiple comments with multiple suggestions as work arounds, alternatively, I maintain a CF7 plugin extension, [The Smart-grid layout for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/), which allows you to publish HTML rich messages,

```php
add_filter( 'cf7sg_submission_response', 'html_response', 10, 4 );
function html_response( $msg, $status, $data, $cf7key ) {
  if( 'my-form' === $cf7key && 'mail_sent' === $status){
      $msg= 'Hello click <a href="#here">here</a>';
  }
  return $msg;
}
```